# Managing images and other media for large website

Tags: php, apache, web-applications

I am currently developing a big web application.  Users will be able to post images as well as music files to my server.  I am using PHP with Codeigniter framework and work off an Apache server from A2hosting.com .  I was wondering how I will be able to manage space.  I know that they offer unlimited storage but I know that I am going to run into issues if too many people are uploading too much.

How is the best way to deal with this? Would you have your own separate hosting plan for storing all this media?  Could it be stored in a through a third party?  Will my site eventually be slowing down because there is way too much memory that I am holding for people?

I guess I would kind of like to know what issues I am going to be running into?  My project is almost completed and I want to avoid any large scale errors that may occur.  I am the only one working on this project so man power is pretty precious, as well as time.

Any help and insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone offering you "unlimited storage" at a fixed rate is having you on.

We put our media files on Amazon S3, which is designed to handle [trillions of files](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/amazon-s3-the-first-trillion-objects.html).

Comment: Thanks bro.  This really helps.  How easy was it to integrate this into your application?  Were there any drawbacks?

Comment: Our user-submitted content actually goes directly to Amazon S3 via their HTTP POST support (http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html) and it's made a huge difference for us. We used to have to deal with syncing our servers across and running out of space all the time. No drawbacks I've seen, and if you're hosting on EC2 it's incredibly fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you do host the uploaded data locally please don't place your uploads folder anywhere in your web root or in a place directly accessible by remote users. Expanding your storage is easy but recovering from a total website or server compromise is not!